# How do I change a template's image formatting settings in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, text-formatting

I've been given the task of writing a Microsoft Word template which auto-formats images with a small, blue, 0.75pt outline.

[image: Screenshot with blue outline]

This means individually formatting every image as it is added.

[image: Formatting image with outline]

[Microsoft's documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-default-settings-for-new-documents-430B4132-E129-46E4-97D2-19C326352C7F) states that it ***is*** possible to change the default image settings by creating a template, but it unfortunately doesn't specify how.

**How can I change the default image formatting for a Microsoft Word 2010 template?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that's possible. Word templates are just template documents which you can start editing and save as new documents; customizations are achieved through pre-saving styles and some content, but styles cannot customize images, and there is no default style for images.

I think your best bet would be to create a macro which modifies the selected image (or eventually all images in the document), see this link for more details: [Record a Macro to Modify a Picture Border](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother/record-a-macro-to-modify-a-picture-border/66dcfd78-cff9-4f11-93ff-10de1a2447d8)

Comment: If it can't be done on a per-document basis, would it be possible to locally change Word's default image settings for all documents?

Comment: Even in Word 2016, there are only 3 application-wide settings regarding image size and quality.